# Backbone.js - decoupling a data source?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, decoupling

I have this Backbone model:

```
graphModel
 attributes
   country
   indicator
   year
```

With a corresponding view:

```
graphView
 render()
   this.model.get(...)
```

The application also has a general datasource to which csv data is loaded:

```
dataSource
  indicators
    indicatorA
      country
        year
    indicatorB
      countries
        years
```

Every time the model attributes are changed, I'd like to check if data for that combination of attributes is loaded, before firing change events.

**My question is: What is a good way of decoupling the data source from the Backbone model and view so that I can easily try with injected mock data?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear when you're talking about the application having a data source populated with CSV data whether you're speaking about the server side of an app that Backbone then talks to or something client side.

But either way. I can speak to our experiences on some of this decoupling stuff. We often build models and use Backbone's ability to have "default" values like this example from the Backbone docs:

var Meal = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    "appetizer":  "caesar salad",
    "entree":     "ravioli",
    "dessert":    "cheesecake"
  }
});

With a model pre-populated like that we can then tie a view to the model and render that data to the page. Similarly, if you have any other source you can think of for easily getting the data you want (a canned file can be loaded with jQuery's .load() function or the contents of a text area could be dumped in via the model's .set() function).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you have single URL for different models and you want to somehow check it before you set or change model.

You can use `parse()` method on model to change it's content, see http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse